# MySQL Table is Huge Where Only Text Values Are Stored

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

I am using LAMP Stack...And one of my db table wp_options (Rows: 10,600) is now about 194+ GB in size... Not sure why the size growing so much huge... As far as i am concern most of the records are texts.... but texts should not be that size... is there any blob file or something?? not familiar with that though... Please suggest anything to analyze what is taking up the space??

[image: Table Rows]

Comment: Please instead of downvoting... suggest me any solution or what is wrong with the question??? I am in trouble so please help

Comment: possibly the solution to fix is same. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346860/wp-options-is-gb-in-size

Comment: You may want to also find out first which records take up the maximum space. Try SELECT *, LENGTH(fieldname) FROM wp_options ORDER BY LENGTH(fieldname) DESC

Answer (score 0):

Check the WP plugins.  Some of them create thousands of "options" and fail to clean up after themselves.